# Keep track of running numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a running number for an invoice that I need to keep track of so that the next invoice created would increment from it. **How should I store this number?**

I can think of a couple but they don't seem to be ideal.

- query the last invoice created and increment from it
- store it in another table use for storing just this running number

Comment: Why can't you just use the id?

Comment: @Huy because there are many types of invoice which has their own running number, I could if I create a separate model for all of them.